# How to return mysqli connect_error over 2 function in 2 classes PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the dbc.inc.php file. inside of it there are connect function that connects me to the DB.
In the test.inc.php file i have the runQuery function inside of a "Test" class. The "Test" class extends from the "Dbc" class allocated in the dbc.inc.php file.

The runQuery($db, $sql) runs query. But if error happend or warning he is not showing the error. i belive that im having a syntax mistake.

For the testing interesst i have given the wrong fieldname in my $sql statment. The error is hapenning but is not showing.

dbc.inc.php

```
<?php

class Dbc{
private $serverName;
private $userName;
private $password;

protected function connect($dbName = NULL){
    $this->serverName = "localhost";
    $this->userName   = "root";
    $this->password   = "";
    
    $conn = new mysqli($this->serverName, $this->userName, $this->password, $dbName);
    if (!$conn) {
        die("<h3>Error Connecting to the Database.</h3><h4 style=\"color: red\">". $conn->connect_error . "</h4>");
        
        
    } else {
        return $conn;
    }
    
}

}
?>
```

test.inc.php

```
<?php

 require 'dbc.inc.php';

 class Test extends Dbc{

function runQuery($db, $sql){
    $query = mysqli_query($this->connect($db), $sql);
    if (!$query) {
        echo "no Query";
        echo $this->connect($db)->connect_error;
        return 0;
    } else {
        echo "Query EXEC";
        return 1;
    }
}

 }


?>
```

The test code

```
$conn = new Test;
$conn->runQuery("tch_phn", "UPDATE `employee` SET `uiS`='Assad' WHERE `uid`='Assad' ");
```

The error is i have given a unknown field name (`uiS` has to be `uid`). How can i do this?

Comment: You just need to enable error reporting and remove the `if` statements from the code. See also [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439) and [Should I manually check for errors when calling “mysqli_stmt_prepare”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62216426/1839439)

Comment: Yes. i have understand the idea. im not sure how to do it in my code.... would you please do it so i can see it and learn from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `Dbc` class. It is not useful to you at all at its current state. The mysqli connection is always the same three lines of code and there is no point to add a class for it.

To connect to DB using mysqli use:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db_name');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset
```

Then you can write a class which will take the DB connection as a parameter in `__construct()`.

```
class Test {
    private \mysqli $db = null;
    public function __construct(\mysqli $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    function runQuery($sql) {
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    }
}
```

That's it. Although you really should try to create a more useful mysqli abstraction class, or even better, use PDO instead. If you want to write mysqli wrapper class you can start with the following idea (adjust to your needs):

```
class DBClass extends mysqli {
    public function __construct($host = null, $username = null, $passwd = null, $dbname = null, $port = null, $socket = null) {
        // Enable error reporting and call mysqli constructor
        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
        parent::__construct($host, $username, $passwd, $dbname, $port, $socket);
        $this->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the proper charset which should be utf8mb4 99.99% of the time
    }

    public function safeQuery(string $sql, array $params = []): ?array {
        // Prepare statement:
        $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
        // If the statement has parameters then bind them all now
        if ($params) {
            $stmt->bind_param(str_repeat("s", count($params)), ...$params);
        }
        // Execute it and get results if there are any
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($result = $stmt->get_result()) {
            return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_BOTH);
        }
        // If the query was INSERT or UPDATE then return null
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you can execute any SQL statement with a simple one line even when using mysqli.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/a/61566985/1839439

Comment: Thank you very much. the PDO is a bit confusing to me. i didnt really understand the code you wirte last. but the answer is right.

Comment: @PDO is the proper DB library to use with PHP. You really should avoid mysqli at all cost. What is confusing to you in the code I shared? Is it the connection or the prepared statement bit?

Comment: The safeQuery() is confusing. the example i wrote above is meant to be used in the set and get functions in a particular class. do you mind if a post it so you may give me a better idea on doing it?

Comment: Try to understand the comments I wrote. I explained a little bit. Try to build a similar function yourself. You can use this function to execute any SQL statement you need. It's a generic use function. If you understand the idea of prepared statements you should be able to understand `safeQuery` function. If you have new question or a new problem then you can start a new question on Stack Overflow. Even if the new question is about my code/answer.